# Error running django with gunicorn and circus

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, circusd

I want to run django on an ubunu 14.04 machine , using gunicorn and circus. when I start gunicorn manually, it works fine, but when I try to run it with circus , this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
  File "/path_to_my_app/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "/path_to_my_app/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    import traceback
ImportError: No module named 'traceback'
```

I have tried deleting virtual environment and creating it again, I have tested the ini file ...

any ideas?

Comment: please, show pip freeze, does traceback in list modules?

Comment: check this https://github.com/circus-tent/circus/issues/1010

Comment: @itzMEonTV Thank you ! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution which itzMEonTV suggested, works fine. I don't know what the problem is though! I am using the same ini file that I have on another server. the only difference between these two systems, is the OS version. PYTHONPATH works fine on ubuntu 16.04 but not on 14.04.

anyway, the [link](https://github.com/circus-tent/circus/issues/1010) suggested by itzMEonTV  solved my problem.